# Implementing reusable methods for Ant Design validator (ReactJS)

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am trying to implement a validator as per the documentation provided by ant design https://ant.design/components/form/

The methods are working when they are placed in the same class/component.
The validator method uses a callback method that throws a string where the validation method was called.

What i am trying to achieve is that i want the same validator method to be reuseable. When I placed them in another class it's not working.

I have tried moving it to a different class and export the method. On importing the method in the same component callback is not working.

Here is my method that I am using for validation:

```
mobileCountryCodeValidator = (rule, value, callback) => {
    const { getFieldValue } = this.props.form
    let countryCode = getFieldValue('phoneCountryCode')
    if (countryCode === '92') {
      if (value.substring(0, 1) !== '3') {
        callback('Number should start with 3 for Pakistan.')
      }
      callback()
    } else if (countryCode === '966') {
      if (value.substring(0, 2) !== '05') {
        callback('Number should start with 05 for Saudi Arabia.')
      }
      callback()
    }
  }
```

This is where I am calling the above method.

```
<FormItem validateStatus="validating">
    {getFieldDecorator('phoneNumber', {rules: [
        { required: true, message: 'Please input your phone number.' },
        { len: 10, message: 'Phone number should be 10 digits long.' },
        { validator: this.numbersValidator },
        { validator: this.mobileCountryCodeValidator },
     ]})(
          <Input placeholder="Enter Mobile Number" />
     )}
</FormItem>
```

So what I am expecting is that how should I be able to move the `mobileCountryCodeValidator` method to another class so It can become a reuseable method. So I would be able to use them in other components too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validator needs the `form` object.

you should be able to do that with a little bit of closure

```
mobileCountryCodeValidator = (form) => (rule, value, callback) => {
    const { getFieldValue } = form;  // this line changed
    let countryCode = getFieldValue('phoneCountryCode')
    if (countryCode === '92') {
      if (value.substring(0, 1) !== '3') {
        callback('Number should start with 3 for Pakistan.')
      }
      callback()
    } else if (countryCode === '966') {
      if (value.substring(0, 2) !== '05') {
        callback('Number should start with 05 for Saudi Arabia.')
      }
      callback()
    }
  }
```

and

```
<FormItem validateStatus="validating">
    {getFieldDecorator('phoneNumber', {rules: [
        { required: true, message: 'Please input your phone number.' },
        { len: 10, message: 'Phone number should be 10 digits long.' },
        { validator: this.numbersValidator },
        { validator: this.mobileCountryCodeValidator(this.props.form) },
     ]})(
          <Input placeholder="Enter Mobile Number" />
     )}
</FormItem>
```

Comment: Can I ask that how was form object related to the call back method?

Comment: because from your code you use `this.props.form` means you are using uncontrolled form, which means you use `Form.create`, which inject the form state to the children, which is necessary for the validator to work

Comment: I logged into Stackoverflow just to upvote this answer. Thank you very much. I had been trying this since morning. Makes code much cleaner and reusable.